# Tag div put some word will change the div position?

Tags: html, css

I use **div** to make layout .

The problem is `<div class="c">1</div>` ,

I put number 1 in it  `<div class="c">1</div>`, The  **div** will be below.

I remove number 1 `<div class="c"></div>`, The  **div** will be up .

I am confused why text in **div** will change the place.

This is my code in given below:

```css
div.content {
    border: 5px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0;

    width:1000px;
    
    height: 800px;
    }




    div.a {

    border: 5px solid rgb(212, 69, 69);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;

    height: 600px;
    
    font-size: 16px;


    display: inline-block;

    }

    div.b {
    border: 5px solid rgb(11, 141, 22);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);

    height: 500px;

    font-size: 16px;

    display: inline-block;
    }

    div.c {
    border: 5px solid rgb(219, 7, 209);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">
         
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div class="b">

            <div class="c">1</div>

        </div> 


    </div>
```

Comment: The display:inline-block cause it.

Comment: Your code is just fine , this is happening becuase of the unpresent alignment, i.e `div.b` just set the `vertical-align: bottom;` to that green div , then it will work fine .

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which you wanted.

`position:absolute;` will get your table to line up directly to the right of the green box. This happens because the default setting is for your boxes to be `relative` of their parent container. Changing this to absolute allows it to work almost independantly.

OR

Change your `display:` style to `block;` instead of `in-line` if you wanted to display your box underneath. This works as it's no longer forced to be `in-line` with the box above it and can now be displayed neatly below.

Here's a snippet of the `absolute` positioning:

```css
div.content {
    border: 5px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0;

    width:1000px;
    
    height: 800px;
    }




    div.a {

    border: 5px solid rgb(212, 69, 69);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;

    height: 600px;
    
    font-size: 16px;


    display: inline-block;

    }

    div.b {
    border: 5px solid rgb(11, 141, 22);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    position:Absolute;
    height: 500px;

    font-size: 16px;

    display: inline-block;
    }

    div.c {
    border: 5px solid rgb(219, 7, 209);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">
         
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div class="b">

            <div class="c">1</div>

        </div> 


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just **add float left** to **div.a** and **div.b** will work for your current requirement.

If you have some specific requirements, do share.

```css
div.content {
    border: 5px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
  }

  div.a {
    float:left;
    border: 5px solid rgb(212, 69, 69);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  div.b {
    float:left;
    border: 5px solid rgb(11, 141, 22);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    height: 500px;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  div.c {
    border: 5px solid rgb(219, 7, 209);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you needed the box to always be up just add a **float: left; to .content > div** like this to the css file.

```css
div.content {
    border: 5px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0;

    width:1000px;
    
    height: 800px;
    }




    div.a {

    border: 5px solid rgb(212, 69, 69);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;

    height: 600px;
    
    font-size: 16px;


    display: inline-block;

    }

    div.b {
    border: 5px solid rgb(11, 141, 22);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);

    height: 500px;

    font-size: 16px;

    display: inline-block;
    }

    div.c {
    border: 5px solid rgb(219, 7, 209);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    }

    .content > div{
    float:left;
 
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">
         
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div class="b">

            <div class="c">1</div>

        </div> 


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In div class **a & b** you  have to add "**float: left;**" in CSS. So this will set your div in proper relative place. While you can also add a css for content

```
/*use this css code*/

div.content {

  /*use this if you need while you are adding more than one div */

  /*float: left;*/
  border: 5px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;    
  width: 1000px;    
  height: 800px;
}

div.a {
  border: 5px solid rgb(212, 69, 69);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

div.b {
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid rgb(11, 141, 22);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.c {
  border: 5px solid rgb(219, 7, 209);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

use this CSS in your code.[image]